# Speed up the initial TensorFlow startup

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Each time I run a Python code using TensorFlow (CPU), such as:

```
import keras
```

I see this:

```
2020-10-30 15:27:20.518894: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-10-30 15:27:20.518894: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2020-10-30 15:27:23.713077: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2020-10-30 15:27:23.713077: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:313] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-10-30 15:27:23.716077: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: User1-PC
2020-10-30 15:27:23.716077: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: User1-PC
2020-10-30 15:27:23.729078: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x10cad0c0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-10-30 15:27:23.729078: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
Using TensorFlow backend.
```

If I sum all the waiting time, there is ~ 10 seconds of waiting time.

**Is there a way to speed up this process?** Especially if I'm using TensorFlow for inference (and not training), I don't want to have to wait 10 seconds on each startup of the engine.

---

NB: Of course, when my code will be ready, I'll keep the process using TensorFlow constantly running, and I'll use some sort of inter-process communication, to avoid restart the whole program.

My question here is mostly for the **prototyping** stages, when you *often* need to restart the program: when prototyping, having to wait 10 or 15 seconds on each script start is highly unconvenient.

Comment: Can you use a python notebook using jupyter?  You say that the issue is in prototyping... when I'm prototyping and want fast re-compile of a few lines of code or a whole class, using a jupyter notebook is FANTASTIC and WAY FASTER than re-running a file.

Comment: Also, another trick I use for quick testing is a wrapper that caches results of network to file.  This way the import statements are skipped if my test code is just using the same data in and I'm just working with other code that is digesting the output of the network. I've used this for language embeddings and image embedding extraction.  Lastly, I also something use just `np.random.rand(...)` to generate data in-lieu of running tensorflow in order to test all the post neuralnetwork handling.

Answer (score 3):

For your inference problem, you'll probably want a longer-lived process that you can request inference results from, maybe over HTTP, gRPC, XML-RPC, named pipes, reading files from a directory...?

Failing that, get a faster machine or disk. On my machine, starting a new Python process and importing Keras takes about 2 seconds:

```
$ pip install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Downloading tensorflow-2.3.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl (165.2 MB)
[...]
Successfully installed absl-py-0.11.0 astunparse-1.6.3 cachetools-4.1.1 chardet-3.0.4 gast-0.3.3 google-auth-1.23.0 google-auth-oauthlib-0.4.2 google-pasta-0.2.0 grpcio-1.33.2 h5py-2.10.0 idna-2.10 keras-preprocessing-1.1.2 markdown-3.3.3 numpy-1.18.5 oauthlib-3.1.0 opt-einsum-3.3.0 packaging-20.4 protobuf-3.13.0 pyasn1-0.4.8 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8 requests-2.24.0 requests-oauthlib-1.3.0 rsa-4.6 tensorboard-2.3.0 tensorboard-plugin-wit-1.7.0 tensorflow-2.3.1 tensorflow-estimator-2.3.0 termcolor-1.1.0 werkzeug-1.0.1 wrapt-1.12.1
$ time python -c 'import tensorflow.keras as keras'

________________________________________________________
Executed in    2.02 secs   fish           external
   usr time    2.85 secs  118.00 micros    2.85 secs
   sys time    0.62 secs  946.00 micros    0.62 secs
```

Comment: *"For your inference problem, you'll probably want a longer-lived process that you can request inference results from, maybe ..."*: Yes I'll do that, for sure, but during the "prototyping" stage, this initial 10 second startup is a bit unconvenient.

Comment: You can try to make sure you’re using the CPU only version of tensorflow. Might stop it from doing all the CUDA checks